# Can normal physics laws be simulated in Digital physics?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, physics

[Physics](http://www.physics.org/article-questions.asp?id=18) is defined as the study of an object {matter or energy} with its interaction with other objects:

> Physics is the study of matter, energy, and the interaction between them.

On the other hand, [Digital physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics) is  based on computations and information.

> Digital physics is a collection of theoretical perspectives based on the premise that the universe is, at heart, describable by information, and is therefore computable.

If we have a universal computer {a universal turing machine} and a program that can compute the evolution of the universe (Digital Physics) running on it, can this specific program simulate our normal physics laws like the classical mechanics laws or quantum mechanics laws ?

1- Can we simulate a universe with its fundemental laws {i.e physics} and change these laws by a universal computer accordingly ?

2- How a simulation of a universe (if any) with fundemental laws {like physics} would help to further understanding in physics ?

3- Is there any form of universal turing machine to apply these simulation ?

Comment: I don't see how to give a useful answer to this question without more explanation what you are asking.  What are your thoughts?  When you ask "...given a program that can compute the evolution of the universe, can this specific program simulate our normal physics laws like the classical mechanics laws or quantum mechanics laws?" it seems like the only possible answer is "If quantum mechanics *is* a complete theory of how the universe evolves, then of course the answer is yes, by definition" -- what more are you looking for?  I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: I am thinking about a universe that can be simulated on a universal computer, from that universe is it possible to implement some laws like gravity law in it ?  
my question would be, how the gravity law would look like in a simulated universer on a computer ?  
A very basic rule in math is (-x != x) => how this law can be implemented on the simulated universe ? what would happen if i changed it so it would be (-x = x) in that simulated universe ... thats what i am trying to understand.

Comment: it is more or less an open question of physics whether physics is really computable. there are a lot of bordering-on-uncomputable aspects aka "fringe phenomena". almost all physics theory is about the computable aspects, but there seems to be endless (increasingly narrow) anomalies that dont fit into the models. although some anomalies/ question are quite large & play a large role eg dark matter/ energy, black holes, universe expansion etc... asked a related questions on [physics.se] recently but it got deleted :(

Comment: Please note, a Universal Turing Machine is just one that can simulate any other Turing machine, it has no relation to "universe" in the physics sense, and it definitely can NOT solve all problems.

Comment: @vzn so what do you suggest on reading more on these things, what would be a good source to answer the question of whether physics is computable or not, i would be really interested in knowing this & thanks for your answer. 

@ jmte yes exactly, what i am trying to say is for example you can construct a system similar to Conway's game of Life on a universal turing machine, this system itself is a universe right?  

For universal turing machine, why it would not solve all problems ? if you can encod the problem correctly then the machine would already halt when there is an answer, i am right ?

Comment: wikipedia/ [digital physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics) has a lot of citations. the area is controversial with Wolfram a leading theorist in the area. 't Hooft is a nobel prize winner writing extensively on it. also suggest drop by [chat] when you have the rep.

Comment: @Henryakpo when you say "the system itself is a universe," what do you mean? This feels like buzzwords with no actual meaning. There are undecidable problems, which no Turing machine, no matter how powerful, can solve, like the Halting problem. There is no way to encode "infinite-search" problems that guarantee a Turing machine will always halt.

Comment: @jmite, sorry for the confusion ...  what i mean with a universe or a system is a continous running cellular automaton structure (like Conway's game of life => http://www.tamats.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/conway.png), these patterns you see in the picture are designed by you the user, you take a constructor and place it somewhere and put two gliders behind it ( here three objects are taken as an input) and then you run the program to see how it will look like,

Comment: what i am trying to explain is that you can build these patterns (almost the same patterns) by defining some general functions (in the system) to be applied when a specific criteria is met, i.e when two gliders collide => create a constructor behind them, and a single input (as just one object like a glider), from here when you run the system with just one object as an input with the functions implemented, the system will create a similar picture like the one above without user involvement,

Comment: how this is related to physics is, these objects (the input) are built or encoded in numbers (integers) and the functions also are implemented in the system as integers => so this was my question if i can implement physics (laws) to that system by encoding them as integers.



For the halting problem, if a Universal Cellular Automaton == Turing machine, then surely it will halt, the problem is not about the machine will halt or not, the problem is about how you encode the information and how the machine understands it,

Comment: what we know about turing machines is that given a tape contains zeros and ones, you tell the machine to apply a set of rules defined by you to decode the text for example by moving left or right and changing the cell's value, but what a turing machine misses is a fundemental law, a fundemental physics or mathematical law, when there is such a law taken as the only and the main rule set for the machine, applied on any input, then surely that machine would always halt.

Comment: The good  news is , there is such a law and it exists but it is difficult to explain the concept when scientific journals takes a lot of time to publish such proofs, soon it will be published.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The laws of physics are stated in the form of mathematics. Differential equations are pretty popular, for example classical mechanics can be described with differential equations.

You can program a computer to take some initial state of the universe and apply all the laws of physics to it to get a new state of the universe. This comes with a couple of caveats. First, you need to somehow discretize the time steps you compute. Differential equations operate under continuous time, but a numerical simulations does discrete steps. It's reasonably well understood how to do that without losing too much precision. This brings us to a second problem, precision. Physics is generally formulated using real (or complex) variables, but computers only deal with finite precision. Usually this is ok, because in reality we can also only distinguish things with finite precision. Lastly, our laws of physics are not yet complete. There are a number of phenomena where we don't really know what's supposed to happen, so the simulation won't represent the real universe perfectly, even if we start with a proper starting state (which we can also only guess) and use sufficient precision and sufficiently small time steps.

Note that it is completely impractical to simulate all laws of physics as we know them on real computers. Even simulating single molecules with all relevant laws is very hard even for supercomputers.

Nevertheless, physicists simulate things all the time, sometimes using bold approximations to cut down the required computation. It's really important in physics to do simulations. [Wikipedia has on overview article on Computational Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_physics) and Richard Feynman has written a classic paper called [Simulating Physics with Computers](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/Feynman.pdf).

It is of course also possible to tweak the laws of Physics a bit and do your simulation. You can change the equations, or the constants and see what happens to your simulated system. You can for example find that changing some constants just a little [produces an inhospitable universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe#Examples).

Now I don't think it's possible to change fundamental mathematical truths in your simulated universe, because Physics makes no prediction about mathematics. You can't change the laws of Physics such that 1+1 != 2.

Comment: more on scientific/ physics determinism see [Laplace demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon). more on precision/ sensitivity to initial conditions see [butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)

Comment: @adrian man you made my day with your answer + vzn's ... i would surely read the resources you both provided but just one thing -> what if laws of physics can be simulated or encoded as equations or constants  on a computer, how useful that would be ?  surely 1+1 is always 2 but what if there exists a universe when only  the law (x)=(-x) is applied alone or along with other rules ? iam sure there exists a logical algorithm that would make (x)=(-x) by somehow.

Comment: @Henryakpo Mathematicians sometimes look at what happens when you change basic axioms. It's still maths though. For example you get different [kinds of geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry) if you change your assumptions a bit. There has been an interesting period in mathematics when we tried to find [which axioms are truly necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics).

Comment: Ya, i just read about it ... well i can say both axioms are helpful in different ways but more interestingly when you use both of them at once, i am talking based on my experience of both axioms with cellular automata, but defining which axioms are necessary ... necessary for what ??

Answer (score 1):

It is currently believed that physics requires real numbers.  Digital computers cannot work with real numbers.  We spend a great deal of time in simulations trying to cope with the difference between real numbers and IEE-754 floating point representations of those numbers.  We also try to avoid operating in the known environments where those differences are resolvable (which occurs in many chaotic systems).  We also abuse statistics, and seek to argue that a sampling of universes can describe a statistical variable in the real world.

One option would be to do symbolic manipulation, if you could identify a set of symbols which fully identified state of the universe.  However, the ability to model *our* universe that way is highly questionable, due to self-referential issues.  Read about Godel's incompleteness theorem if you're interested in questions about predicting the state of our universe, not just an arbitrarily specified universe.

Comment: Well, i got you idea clearly => so if that simulated universe just contains integers (all positive) there is no way to implement physics law rights ?  what if we transferred our current physics laws that involves floating points to just integers and implemented them, what would it involve, how hard it can be ?  surely i will read godel's imcompleteness but i would be very interested in knowing things in physics that involve decimal points or represented as floating points.

Comment: Floating points (like IEE-754 floats) are still not real numbers.  There is actually a mapping from every floating point operation you can do to a set of integer operations.  Floats do a better job of approximating real numbers than normal integers do, because they capture traits of those real numbers that we consider important.  However, there are plenty of cases where the details needed to simulate our universe are not well captured in floating point arithmetic (at least to the best of our scientific knowledge to date... we may always learn something new tomorrow)

Comment: An easy example is catastrophic cancellation of floating point numbers.  There are things you can do to work around that issue, but it is a well understood way to demonstrate limits of floating point numbers.  Chaotic systems, however, are much more resistant to being modeled in floating point numbers, so much so that I would make the claim that dynamic chaotic systems cannot be fully captured in floating point numbers.  Edward Lorentz found this with his weather simulator, and we've been dealing with the results ever since.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad to be useful I think. The general answer is, of course, **no** because all computers we have operate in a discrete manner while laws of physics seem to be pretty damn continuous (even with quantum mechanics in the way). So you'll always have rounding errors, steps which have nothing in-between and insufficiently random behavior.

I think the best example is just simple bouncing balls problem. If you have ever implemented it you know that, as the program goes on, balls get stuck in each other, as in this image I've drawn for you:

[image: image description]

This is one of many possible cases where your program breaks laws of physics and what you have to do is to either calculate collision before it happens or calculate what should've happened once laws of physics have been broken.

Comment: so the problem is about the representation of decimal numbers and how they will appear, but i don't understand why physics cannot only be represented as integers ??? would you please provide something from physics that require writing it as decimal ? 

The images explains it clearly, but i am wondering what if we implement rules of physics that only involve integers without any rounding process or objects that require them, or represent the law of physics as a whole as  integers (without decimals) would that be possible ?

Comment: But physics doesn't happen in integers, which is whole problem. Man, just look at a circle. Π is a number that not only isn't integer, but can't even be represented by float of any size apart of indefinite. Which means that some calculations, such as circle circumference will never be precise unless you have indefinite amount of memory at hand. So the idea of simulating physics *for real* breaks pretty soon.